# Get ValueMembers of a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, checkboxlist

I have a linq Query that I have bound to a Checkbox list using Windows forms

```
var webresourcesFromCRM = from w in orgSvcContext.CreateQuery("webresource")                                                   
                          select new
                          {
                              webresourceid = w["webresourceid"],
                              name = w["name"]
                          };
```

I have used the DisplayMember and ValueMember  properties when binding

```
cblWebResources.DataSource = webresourcesFromCRM;
cblWebResources.DisplayMember = "name";
cblWebResources.ValueMember = "webresourceid";
```

the above code works great. However My problem is I want to get the ValueMember of the checked items. I've tried every combination of             cblWebResources.SelectedItems or cblWebResources.SelectedIndices. I just want to be able to loop through my selected items and out put each ValueMember in a windows form app.

I've try other posts like but no luck this is a windows form app

```
var selectedItems = checkedUsers.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                      .Where(li => li.Selected)
                                      .Select(li => int.Parse(li.Text));
int sum = selectedItems.Sum();
string items = string.Join(",", selectedItems);
```

Comment: Winforms doesn't have `CheckBoxList`; I assume you mean `CheckedListBox`, yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `CheckedListBox` conveniently has both:

```
 var c = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems;
 var s = checkedListBox1.SelectedItems;
```

Now you get the intersection:

```
var cs = c.Cast<object>().Where(i => s.Contains(i));
var sc = s.Cast<object>().Where(i => c.Contains(i));
```

Sadly `CheckedListBoxes` don't support `MultiSelect`, so the second form should be better.

What it sadly also doesn't have is an option to bind the `Checkboxes` :-(

Comment: Not quite what I need I figured it out. I need to cast the checked items

Comment: Well, ok; as long as my post helped to find `CheckedItems` and `Cast` it was not all in vain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to cask my checked items to an object

foreach (var item in cblWebResouces.CheckedItems.Cast())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.webresourceid);
        }